# Jquery to add class to table row only applies to first row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to use jquery to add a class to the table row element but it only works on the first row. I am populating the table using a mysql database and using a *while* loop to display the table.

After pressing the button I want each row to change color when hovered over. The class I want applied to the table row element:

```
.hoverChange:hover
 {

     background-color: #66ccff

 }
```

The table and while loop which displays all the data:

```
               <table border = 1> 
                <tr>
                <th>  ID  </th>
                <th>  Name  </th>
                <th>  Description  </th>
                <th>  Type  </th>
                <th>  Price  </th>
                <th>  Cost Price  </th>
                <th>  Stock Level </th>
                <th>  EAN  </th>
                </tr> 

                 <?php

                 while ($product_Info = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


                         ?>

                        <tr id = tableRows>

                         <?php
                         echo "<td>" . $product_Info["product_ID"] . "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $product_Info["product_Name"] . "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $product_Info["product_Desc"] . "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $product_Info["product_Type"] . "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $product_Info["product_Price"] . "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $product_Info["product_Cost"] . "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $product_Info["product_Stock"] . "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $product_Info["product_ean"] . "</td>">                          


                         echo "<tr>";

                 }

                echo "</table>";
```

The button:

```
<button type="button" id = "updateBtn" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
```

And finally the jquery I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#updateBtn").click(function(){
    $('#tableRows').addClass('hoverChange');
});
 });
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard oh right, totally oversaw that. Anyways your answer explained whats wrong here

Comment: Thank you @JayBlanchard, it is working fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a class instead of an ID for your table rows. [ID's Must Be Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

You have some stray spaces and you're not quoting attributes. This could also become problematic in the future, i.e.

```
<tr class="myClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `class` instead of `id` attribute for repeating objects. ID should be unique for the whole page.

And be careful with spaces in your code ;)